# Mostrar checkbox ya marcados con jquey de acuerdo a un registro de la base de datos MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax

Tengo un fullcalendar y al dar clic en algún día me va a mostrar un formulario, el usuario ingresa los datos normal y debe seleccionar unas personas asignadas a ese evento con unos checkbox. (**Ahí todo bien**).

[Imagen del calendario con eventos ya creados](https://ibb.co/kjMWSp)

[Imagen del Formulario de registro](https://ibb.co/i3W4f9)

El usuario al dar clic en un evento ya creado va a mostrar los registros que él ya ha ingresado y que ya está guardado en la base de datos:

[Imagen del formulario con los datos que el usuario ya registró](https://ibb.co/nOshYU)

[Imagen de la muestra de la base de datos, y el campo asignados](https://ibb.co/jt05L9)

Código jquery donde muestra la información de los eventos en los inputs:

```
eventClick:function(calEvent,jsEvent,view){

                $('#btnAgregar').prop("hidden",true);
                $('#btnModificar').prop("hidden",false);
                $('#btnFinalizado').prop("hidden",false);


                //Mostrar la información del evento en los inputs           
                FechaHoraCorreo= calEvent.correo.split(" ");
                $('#txtFechaCorreo').val(FechaHoraCorreo[0]);
                $("#txtHoraCorreo").val(FechaHoraCorreo[1]);
                FechaHoraInicio= calEvent.inicio.split(" ");
                $('#txtFechaInicio').val(FechaHoraInicio[0]);
                $("#txtHoraInicio").val(FechaHoraInicio[1]);
                FechaHoraFin= calEvent.fin.split(" ");
                $('#txtFechaFin').val(FechaHoraFin[0]);
                $("#txtHoraFin").val(FechaHoraFin[1]);
                FechaHoraEntrega= calEvent.entrega.split(" ");
                $('#txtFechaEntrega').val(FechaHoraEntrega[0]);
                $("#txtHoraEntrega").val(FechaHoraEntrega[1]);
                $('#txtIdCumplimiento').val(calEvent.idcumplimiento);
                $('#txtTrabajo').val(calEvent.trabajo);
                $('#txtIdEjecucion').val(calEvent.idejecucion);
                $('#txtPm').val(calEvent.pm);
                $('#txtComercial').val(calEvent.comercial);
                $('#txtIdMes').val(calEvent.idmes);


                $("#ModalEventos").modal();
            }
```

¿Cómo hago para que cuando el usuario le de clic en algún evento ya creado me muestre los checkbox ya chekeados de acuerdo a lo que el usuario marcó cuando hizo el registro?

Si por ejemplo le da clic en el Evento 1 me muestre chekeado Erick Gaming, o si le da clic en el evento 2, me muestre chekeados Andres Medina y Nelson Barrios y así con los demás eventos que vaya creando.

Comment: Cuando un checkbox esta marcado, en javascript su valor es true, podrias condicionar que cuando el usuario haga click se muestren los checkbox cuyo valor sea true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya logré solucionarlo:

Solo es hacer esto y listo!

```
                let seleccionados = calEvent.asignados.split(',');

                jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                    seleccionados.forEach(function(nombre) {
                        jQuery(`.txtAsignados[value="${nombre}"]`).prop('checked',true);
                    });
                });

                jQuery('.txtAsignados').prop('checked',false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Al igual que estás usando Jquery para dar valor al resto de campos, puedes usar la propiedad checked del checkbox:

```
$('#idDeTuCheckbox').prop('checked', true);
```

Si tienes almacenados los valores del checkbox, como tienes los del resto de los campos, no te debería de suponer mayor problema.

**EDIT**

```
<?php

    $contador = 1;

    foreach ($sql8 as $row) {   ?>
        <input type="checkbox" id="miID-<?php $contador ?>">
        <?php $contador++;
    } ?>
```

Con eso conseguirías tener cada uno de tus checkbox con una ID diferente. Luego ya tendrías que ver la manera de determinar cuales son los que quieres marcar o no marcar, dependiendo de como hayas almacenados los checkbox en tu base de datos.

Comment: Ya lo había intentado de esa manera, pero solo queda marcado el primer checkbox que está en el formulario del registro. 

Como me muestra en la imagen siempre muestra el primer chekbox marcado y debería de estar marcado Erick Gaming 

Imagen: https://ibb.co/cwphHp

Es que creería que toca hacer algún split, porque cuando el usuario selecciona dos checbox en la base de datos quedan separados con coma ( , ) (El problema es que no se como hacerlo)

Comment: Si nos muestras el HTML del formulario, podríamos ayudarte mejor. Así es un poco dar palos de ciego. Si me dices que no te funciona el Jquery, y sin poder ver el código, me da la sensación de que tienes un problema a la hora de capturar con Jquery el checkbox para otorgarle la propiedad checked. ¿Los capturas, por nombre o clase o lo haces por la ID?

Comment: Esta es la imagen de el formulario donde están los checkbox: https://ibb.co/h3N2Hp

Cabe resaltar que los datos de los checxbox los cargo ya desde una consulta de la base de datos con un campo que se llama primer nombre y primer apellido que están en la BD.

Y yo capturo los datos por el ID

Comment: Creo que ya veo el problema. Tienes a todos los checkbox con la misma ID. Al generarse dinamicamente dentro de un for, les estás asignando a todos la misma id. Para diferenciarlos, inicializaría una variable numérica a 1, que fuese aumentando en cada iteración del bucle y se la vas concatenando a la ID, para tenerlas diferenciadas. Luego ya podrías ir haciéndoles el checked true a las que te interesen.

Comment: Me podría hacer el favor de mostrarme algún código de como sería más o menos, NUNCA he hecho algo así como lo que usted me dice.

Comment: Te lo publico editando mi respuesta.

Comment: Listo ya cada uno tiene su ID diferente con el autoincrementable, y lo que quiero es que el usuario al dar clic en algún evento ya estén marcados los que el registró. Y en la base de datos si marcó dos o más asignados quedan separados por coma ( , ) y si solo seleccionó uno queda normal.

Imágen de como queda en la BD: https://ibb.co/cAK209

Comment: Lo siguiente sería hacerle un explode() al registro de la base de datos. Se trata de una función a la que le pasas el string del delimitador (en tu caso la coma) y el string que deseas "trocear" y te construye un array con ellos. Luego  te quedaría recorrer ese array e ir poniéndolos los checks a los que corespondan.

Comment: Que sepa el explode() se usa con PHP, pero no existe una forma de hacerlo igual, pero con Jquery?

Comment: En Jquery tienes la función split(), que hace exactamente lo mismo nada más que recibiendo como parámetro solamente el caracter delimitador.

Comment: Ya casi me da, necesito hacer un while que me recorra contaAsig y arrayAsig y vaya sumandole uno, pero nose como hacer. Imagen de como lo estoy haciendo : https://ibb.co/frFU79 , Imagen del HTML de asignados: ibb.co/c63MLU

Comment: Ya logré hacer algo como esto, Imagen: https://ibb.co/db53HK , pero al momento de chequearlos siempre me chequea los primeros, por ejemplo tengo 3 cheked y en la base de datos tengo el cheked 1 y 3, me chequea los primeros dos osea cheked 1 y cheked 2. y debería chekearme el 1 y el 3, y no he podido solucionar ese problema.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto:

```
var idEvento = $("#idevento").val();
$.ajax({
    data:  idEvento,
    url:   '?URL_retorna_los_asignados_del_evento',  
    type:  'post',
    dataType: "json",
    success:  function (response){ //response es un array
        $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {//Recorre los checks
            response.forEach(function(e){
                if(e == $(this).prop("name")){//Asumo el valor del label del check en la propiedad name del check
                    $(this).attr("checked","checked"); // Seteamos los asignados                
                }
            });          
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: Ya lo hice de esa forma y tampoco da.